# trouble in installing jaspersoft studio

Tags: eclipse, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to install jaspersoft studio in my eclipse indigo IDE, but progress is keep retaining with below point. i tried with many times, but same thing happening for everytime. Please someone help me on this.

[image]

Comment: Eclipse Indigo is 6 years old, does the release of JasperStudio actually support such an old releae.

Comment: @greg-449: if so, could you please suggest me to get good reporting tool for eclipse jsp project

Comment: I don't know anything about JSP tools. You should look at moving to a more up to date Eclipse. Eclipse Neon (4.6.3) is the current release.